# Axes Labeling Latex like

Tags: plotting, programming

```
plotAreaApprox[f_, a_, b_, n_] := 
 Module[{h = (b - a)/n, rects}, 
  rects = Table[
    Rectangle[{i, 0.}, {i + h, f[i + h/2]}], {i, a, b - h, h}];
  Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}, 
   Epilog -> {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], rects}, 
   ImageSize -> 500, Axes -> False, 
   Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, True}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"I"[\[Phi]], None}, {None, None}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}, FrameTicks -> None]]

plotAreaApprox[(2 #/(1 + #^2)) &, 0., 3, 10]
```

The above code will plot an image in mathematica, I want:

1) to show width of any one rectangle by saying <-$2\pi/T$-> (with arrows, but $2\pi/T$ can be beneath the arrow or in the middle)

2) On the top of the $8$th box $\mathbf{I}(\phi_8)$

3)x-axis starting from 0 and ending at $\pi$ with nothing else in the middle

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: If you're really interested in producing LaTeX in MMA then I highly recommend the MaTeX package produced by (I believe) @Szabolcs, you can find it here: http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html

Comment: Thank you, from graphics -->maths mode, and I was able to solve the issue

Comment: How about answer your question?

Comment: Oh great I will do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another approach is to do everything programmatically.

Add the arrows, line and text to `Epilog`. I also made a small adjustment to the padding so the text would print below the figure.

Note that although the right hand side of the x-axis is labeled π, it is in reality the number 3. You might want to adjust the input `b` value to match the axis label.

```
Plot[f[x], {x, a, b},
  Epilog ->
   {
    EdgeForm[Black],
    FaceForm[None],
    rects,
    Arrow[{{a + 3 h, 2*f[a + 3 h]/5}, {a + 3.4 h, 2*f[a + 3 h]/5}}],
    Arrow[{{a + 4 h, 2*f[a + 3 h]/5}, {a + 3.6 h, 2*f[a + 3 h]/5}}],
    Text[Style["\!\(\*FractionBox[\(2  π\), \(T\)]\)", 
      14], {a + 3.5 h, 2 f[a + 3 h]/7}],
    Text[Style["0", 14], {0, -0.05}],
    Text[Style["π", 14], {3, -0.05}],
    Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(8\)]\)", 
      14], {a + 7.5 h, -0.05}],
    Text[Style["I[\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(8\)]\)]", 
      14], {a + 7.5 h, f[a + 7.5 h] + 0.1}],
    Red,
    Line[{{a + 7.5 h, 0}, {a + 7.5 h, f[a + 7.5 h]}}]
    },
  ImageSize -> 500,
  Axes -> False,
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, True}},
  FrameLabel -> {{"I[ϕ]", None}, {None, None}},
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18},
  FrameTicks -> None,
  PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.03], Scaled[0.03]}, {Scaled[0.07], 
     Scaled[0.03]}}
  ]
 ]

plotAreaApprox[(2 #)/(1 + #^2) &, 0, 3, 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This certainly looks more neat, perhaps a bit more time consuming and require deeper understanding of mathematica.

Comment: @WakasJamil Normally you should wait a day or two before accepting an answer. Someone may come along with a better answer. It is OK to vote if you like it, but best to wait before accepting it.

Answer (score 7):

[image: What I was looking for]

Click on the picture and from the menu bar select Graphics-->drawing tools. A box will open by clicking on $\sum$, we can write mathematical text, one can explore more options.

Answer (score 4):

You may use [`DiscretePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot.html) to do most of the drawing for you with some help from [`FindDivisions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDivisions.html) for the [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html). Then with [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) most of the effort can be placed  in [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) with some help from [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html).

```
plotAreaApprox[f_, a_, b_, n_] :=
 Show[
  Plot[f[x], {x, a, b},
   Ticks -> {FindDivisions[{a, b, π}, 6], None}],
  DiscretePlot[f[x], {x, a, b, (b - a)/n}, 
   ExtentSize -> Center, PlotMarkers -> Point, 
   PlotStyle -> {Gray, EdgeForm[{Thin, Gray}]}, FillingStyle -> White],
  ImageSize -> Large,
  PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[.05], Scaled[.05]}, {Scaled[.15], Scaled[.1]}},
  Epilog -> {
    Inset[Row[{Style["I", Bold], "(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(7\)]\))"}, 
      FrameMargins -> Large, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> None, 
      BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> Scaled[.025]}], 
     With[{p = a + 7 (b - a)/n}, {p, f[p]}], {Center, Bottom}],
    Inset[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(7\)]\)", 
      FontSize -> Scaled[.025]], {a + 7 (b - a)/n, -.065}, {Center, Top}],
    Arrowheads[{-.02, .02}],
    Arrow[{{a + 1/2 (b - a)/n, -0.05}, {a + 3/2 (b - a)/n, -0.05}}],
    Inset[Style[(b - a)/n, Bold], {a + (b - a)/n, -.065}, {Center, Top}]}
  ]
```

Then

```
plotAreaApprox[(2 #/(1 + #^2)) &, 0, π, 10]
```

[image]

And with [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) altering the fineness of the approximation

```
Manipulate[
 plotAreaApprox[(2 #/(1 + #^2)) &, 0, 2 π, n],
 {{n, 7}, 7, 20, 1}]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.